# Open subgroups of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (with usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$) such that $x,y\in G$ implies that $x-y\in G$. Show that $G=\mathbb{R}$.

Clearly $0\in G$. Now how to show that all real numbers are there in $G$? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement of an open subgroup is a union of its cosets, all of which are open, so it is itself open. Therefore an open subgroup is also closed. This leaves very few options, as $\mathbb R$ is a connected space.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Every nonempty open subset of $\Bbb R$ contains at least one open interval.

Comment: Since, $0\in G$, therefore, $y\in G$ implies that $-y\in G$. Thus we have $x+y\in G$ for all $x,y\in G$. Since, $G$ is open, $\exists$ $\epsilon>0$ such that $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)\subset G$. Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then by Archimedian property $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{\vert x\vert}{n}<\epsilon$. Thus $x=\dfrac{x}{n}+\dfrac{x}{n}+... $n times $\in G$. Isn't it?

Comment: Sounds good to me!

Answer (score 1):

More generally, every additive subgroup $G$ of $\mathbb R$ is either discrete or dense (*). Since a discrete set in $\mathbb R$ is not open, $G$ must be dense. Now, the only open and dense subset of $\mathbb R$ is $\mathbb R$ itself.

(*) Consider $\alpha = \inf \{ x \in G : x>0 \}$. Then $G$ is discrete iff $\alpha >0$, in which case $G=\alpha \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $G$ is open, we have $(-2\varepsilon,2\varepsilon)\subset G$ for some small positive $\varepsilon$. If $0\leqslant x\leqslant n\varepsilon$, then $x/n\in G$ hence $n\cdot x/n\in G$, that is $x\in G$. Do the same for $x\leqslant 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following facts:

- Since $G$ is a subgroup hence $0 \in G$.
- Since $G$ is open there is an $\epsilon >0$ such that $(-\epsilon,\epsilon) \subset G$.